# Upgrading python3.4 to python3.6 on ubuntu breaks pip

Tags: python, pip

I'm attempting to install python3.6 on my machine after I currently have python3.4. However, after installation trying to run `pip` under python3.6 gives me the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "pip3", line 7, in <module>
    from pip import main
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip/__init__.py", line 59, in <module>
    from pip.log import logger
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip/log.py", line 9, in <module>
    import colorama, pkg_resources
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pkg_resources.py", line 1520, in <module>
    register_loader_type(importlib_bootstrap.SourceFileLoader, DefaultProvider)
AttributeError: module 'importlib._bootstrap' has no attribute 'SourceFileLoader'
Error in sys.excepthook:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/apport_python_hook.py", line 63, in apport_excepthook
    from apport.fileutils import likely_packaged, get_recent_crashes
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/apport/__init__.py", line 5, in <module>
    from apport.report import Report
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/apport/report.py", line 30, in <module>
    import apport.fileutils
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/apport/fileutils.py", line 23, in <module>
    from apport.packaging_impl import impl as packaging
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/apport/packaging_impl.py", line 20, in <module>
    import apt
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/apt/__init__.py", line 23, in <module>
    import apt_pkg
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'apt_pkg'

Original exception was:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "pip3", line 7, in <module>
    from pip import main
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip/__init__.py", line 59, in <module>
    from pip.log import logger
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip/log.py", line 9, in <module>
    import colorama, pkg_resources
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pkg_resources.py", line 1520, in <module>
    register_loader_type(importlib_bootstrap.SourceFileLoader, DefaultProvider)
AttributeError: module 'importlib._bootstrap' has no attribute 'SourceFileLoader'
```

There were several comments on the internet about that error being encountered, However, none of them contain any actual resolution suggestion. Does anyone have any idea how I could fix this?

Comment: Not a solution, but I recommend using pyenv to manage different python installations in a single machine.

Comment: Run this: `pip install -U pip setuptools`

Answer (score 24):

I managed to solve it without installing anything from sources. 
Here's what I did:

1. First, install `pip` for Python3.x (for some weird reason I didn't have it...)

   ```
   $ sudo apt-get install python3-pip
   ```

   It is an old version...

   ```
   $ pip3 --version
   pip 1.5.4 from /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages (python 3.4)
   ```
2. ... so *upgrade* it to the latest

   ```
   $ sudo pip3 install --upgrade pip
   ```

   Now it is much better

   ```
   $ sudo pip3 --version
   pip 9.0.1 from /usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages (python 3.4)
   ```

---

3. Then upgrade `virtualenvvwrapper`

   ```
   $ sudo pip3 install --upgrade virtualenvwrapper
   # ...
   Successfully installed pbr-3.0.1 six-1.10.0 stevedore-1.22.0 virtualenv-15.1.0 virtualenv-clone-0.2.6 virtualenvwrapper-4.7.2
   ```
4. Now creating a new virtualenv works:

   ```
   $ mkvirtualenv -p `which python3.6` <VIRTUALENV_NAME>
   ```

   `pip` also works:

   ```
   $ pip install django
   # ...
   Successfully installed django-1.11.2 pytz-2017.2

   $ pip freeze
   Django==1.11.2
   pytz==2017.2
   ```

Note: Now I realize it's a bit more than what you asked for, but (without knowing where exactly you failed) I guess you should be OK after step 2.

Comment: not working on mine, I have python2.7, python 3.4 installed. @Igonato 's answer works for me.

Comment: Works fine for me, thanks. I do find that attempting to activate the resulting virtualenv results in 'permission denied'. I'm not convinced that is anything to do with the original problem but I just mention it for completeness.

Answer (score 19):

Had the same problem. Installing python from the source helped.

```bash
# Remove existing python 3.6 if installed with apt
$ sudo apt-get autoremove python3.6

# Get the source
$ wget https://www.python.org/ftp/python/3.6.1/Python-3.6.1.tar.xz
$ tar xvf Python-3.6.1.tar.xz
$ cd Python-3.6.1

# Configure and install
$ sudo ./configure
$ sudo make altinstall

# Success!
$ pip3.6 -V
pip 9.0.1 from /usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages (python 3.6)
```

---

**Edit:** I since discovered [pyenv](https://github.com/pyenv/pyenv). Makes installing and managing different python versions a lot easier. Give it a try!

Comment: The problem is, with `sudo make install` (or `altinstall` or anything similar) you've ended up copying some files that no one keeps the track of - possibly complicating future upgrades or uninstalls. I suggest to consider using something like [`checkinstall`](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/CheckInstall).

Comment: @drdaeman thanks, that's good to know! But I want to leave the answer as is, for simplicity. What do you think? Also, the apt version, hopefully, will get updated and this will become obsolete.

Comment: I guess my comment here would suffice. After all, this is what have actually worked for you. Just wanted to warn that installing stuff outside of any package management may bite at a later time (e.g. if something installs `python3.6` as an apt/dpkg dependency)

Answer (score 4):

I could not solve it by running

```
python3 get-pip.py
```

or

```
pip3 install --upgrade
```

because there I already had issues with pkg_resources.py. Also re-installing the python3-setuptools package from Ubuntu did not help as this still seems to install the one for the version originally installed with the Ubuntu system (3.4 in my case) but I could solve it by manually installing the setuptools via

```
wget https://bootstrap.pypa.io/ez_setup.py -O - | python3
```

Note: python3 points to my new python version 3.6. If thats not the case for you then you would need to run

```
wget https://bootstrap.pypa.io/ez_setup.py -O - | python3.6
```

Answer (score 3):

I replaced Python 3.4 with 3.6 on my Ubuntu 14.04 servers and I had the same problem. In my case the cause seemed to be an ancient system pip:

```bash
$ pip --version
pip 1.5.4 from /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages (python 2.7)
```

I have never installed python3-pip. Instead I solved the error as follows:

```bash
$ sudo pip install --upgrade pip
$ sudo pip install --upgrade virtualenv
```

Answer (score 2):

I was having the same issue. It seems I had 2 versions of `pkg_resources` on my system.

`/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pkg_resources.py`

`/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py`

Moving the old version so my system could find the newer version fixed it for me.

`mv /usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pkg_resources.py /usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pkg_resources.py.back`

Answer (score 0):

You can solve this error by using this command. it will update your **setuptools**

```
python -m ensurepip --upgrade
```

Answer (score 0):

I finally got around this by running:

```
curl https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py -o get-pip.py
python3.6 get-pip.py --force-reinstall
```

After this I can install python3.6 specific packages with:

```
python3.6 -m pip install <packagename>
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, it seems I had a similar problem, but for installing `distribute` as a dependency by `pip`.

I managed to install the dependency in this way (under env):

```
 easy_install distribute==0.7.3
```

A piece of error that I ran into:

```
File "/tmp/pip-build-lvtkw8zs/distribute/pkg_resources.py", line 1518, in <module>
    register_loader_type(importlib_bootstrap.SourceFileLoader, DefaultProvider)
AttributeError: module 'importlib._bootstrap' has no attribute 'SourceFileLoader'
 ----------------------------------------
Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip-build-lvtkw8zs/distribute/
```

Answer (score -2):

Just download the file `get-pip.py` [here](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/installing/) and use this command:

```
sudo python3 get-pip.py
```