# getting error 'No module named pip3' in spite of pip3 being present

Tags: python-3.x, pip, ubuntu-14.04

I'm on ubuntu 14.04. Python 3.4 was present already, I additionally installed python 3.6.

Python 3.6 seemingly runs fine:

```
...:/usr/bin$ python3.6
Python 3.6.3 (default, Oct  6 2017, 00:00:00) 
[GCC 4.8.4] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
```

pip3 also runs fine, but for python 3.6.4 (as expected):

```
...:/usr/bin$ pip3 -V
pip 9.0.1 from /usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages (python 3.4)
```

So I tried running pip3 under python 3.6, but no luck:

```
...:/usr/bin$ python3.6 -m pip3 -V
/usr/bin/python3.6: No module named pip3
```

When searching I found a couple of suggestioons aroundthat error message, but they were all about pip3 not working at all, which is not my problem.

What am I getting wrong?

Comment: `python3.6 -m pip`  (the executable is named `pip3` to differentiate from the other one, the module is named `pip`)

Comment: Thanks a lot. When I do that I run into more trouble, but for those I found: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42558133/upgrading-python3-4-to-python3-6-on-ubuntu-breaks-pip