# Python / PIP broken on Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: python, python-3.x, ubuntu, pip

I think my Python / PIP environment on a Ubuntu 16.04 machine is broken. I just want to install a program using PIP using this command:

```
pip3 install --user ocrmypdf
```

But it doesn't work. When running

```
pip3 --version
```

I get this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/usr/local/bin/pip3", line 7, in <module>
from pip import main
File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip/__init__.py", line 59, in <module>
from pip.log import logger
File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip/log.py", line 9, in <module>
import colorama, pkg_resources
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 971, in _find_and_load
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 955, in _find_and_load_unlocked
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 656, in _load_unlocked
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 626, in _load_backward_compatible
File "/usr/share/python-wheels/setuptools-3.3-py2.py3-none-any.whl/pkg_resources.py", line 1479, in <module>
register_loader_type(importlib_bootstrap.SourceFileLoader, DefaultProvider)
AttributeError: module 'importlib._bootstrap' has no attribute 'SourceFileLoader'
```

Python itself seems to work:

```
root@host /usr/lib # python -V
Python 3.6.3
```

Comment: Have you filed a bug ticket and first searched whether one already exists, of course?

Comment: You mean for Python / PIP or the software I want to install? I think it's a problem with my machine, because I upgraded to Python 3.6 and then it was broken.

Comment: Well, find out which causes the issue! You will have to provide the necessary steps to reproduce the issue and part of that is removing those not necessary.

Comment: The problem is I don't know what caused the issue. Just tried to install the software mentioned above and I ran into those issues with PIP

Comment: If you do not need it for system management it might be a good idea to use virtual environments to separate your project utilities from system ones to gain some stability.

Comment: Have you tried `sudo pip3 install --upgrade pip`? [The answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44354166/4763528) may help.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Upgrading python3.4 to python3.6 on ubuntu breaks pip](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42558133/upgrading-python3-4-to-python3-6-on-ubuntu-breaks-pip)