# Python3.6 failing on Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: python-3.x, pip, ubuntu-14.04

I've installed Python3.6 on a Ubuntu machine running Jenkins as per http://docs.python-guide.org/en/latest/starting/install3/linux/

After the install if I run python3.6 I get nothing.

If I run `update-alternatives --config python3` I get: [image]

If I select 3.6 to run as the default Python3 and then run `pip3 -V` I get:
[image]

However if I run `pip3 -V` while Python3.4 is selected it works fine.

**Update**
I managed to get Python3.6 working as per this SO answer:
[Upgrading python3.4 to python3.6 on ubuntu breaks pip](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42558133/upgrading-python3-4-to-python3-6-on-ubuntu-breaks-pip?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa#43814732)

However pip3.6 fails with the following:
[image]

**Update 2** 
pip 3.6 is now working but installing a package gives the following:

`pip is configured with locations that require TLS/SSL, however the ssl module in Python is not available.
Collecting requests
  Could not fetch URL https://pypi.python.org/simple/requests/: There was a problem confirming the ssl certificate: Can't connect to HTTPS URL because the SSL module is not available. - skipping
  Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement requests (from versions: )
No matching distribution found for requests`

Comment: Not exactly a solution: But did you try `python3 -m pip install <package>` ?

Comment: @GaneshK Python3 won't work at all when pointing at 3.6 instead of 3.4

Comment: What I'm saying is, do whichever python you want to install the package to (i.e whatever name it is referred by, `python`, `python3`, `python3.6`) followed by`-m pip install ...`. But if you mean your python3.6 itself is not working, That's a different issue. [ EDIT ] my bad, okay your python3 has issues. Didn't read that line

Answer (score 0):

After a roundabout approach the following worked:

`wget https://raw.github.com/pypa/pip/master/contrib/get-pip.py`

`python3.4 get-pip.py`

If an error referring to lsb_release appears edit the file (mine was located at `/usr/bin/lsb_release`) and replace `#! /usr/bin/python3 -Es` with `#! /usr/bin/python2.7`

After that cd into the Python3.6.1 directory and run the following:

`./configure --enable-optimizations`

`make -j8`

`make altinstall`